# How do I apply the default theming to views in an android IME?

Tags: android, view, default, ime, theming

I am experimenting with my own android input method, but at the moment I am having trouble with styling / theming. The problem is the following:

The view that I inflate and return in onCreateInputView contains some plain android buttons. I can listen to onClick events on these buttons and it works just fine, but when I click the buttons, their looks don't change, meaning they don't change background color etc. like the normal android buttons do.

I can, however, apply a custom background xml containing a selector:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="CategoryButton">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
</style>
```

button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

This works and the buttons react to user input. However, buttons are not the only views that I plan on using, and it is really difficult to replicate the default android looks. So I tried finding another way. Thinking that the view is missing the default theme, I applied the following background to it:

```
<style name="CategoryButton">
            <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```

But it didn't show any effect. For those interested, here are the contents of @android:drawable/btn_default:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

However, I cannot find the drawables that the states refer to. Might that be the problem?
Do you have suggestions on how I could apply the default theme to all of my views in that IME?

Thank you very much!